# Tensorflow: Why Doesn't Out of Graph Cost Calculation Work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a standard experiment loop that looks like this:

```py
cross_entropy_target = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target_pred - target)))
cost = cross_entropy_target
opt_target = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.00001).minimize(cost)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for mini_batch in range(num_samples / batch_size):
        mb_train_x, mb_train_target = get_mini_batch_stuffs()
        sess.run(opt_target, feed_dict={x: mb_train_x, target: mb_train_target})
```

This runs and converges to a good prediction loss.  Now, same code with a slight modification:

```py
cross_entropy_target = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target_pred - target)))
cross_entropy_target_variable = tf.Variable(0.0)
cost = cross_entropy_target_variable
opt_target = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.00001).minimize(cost)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for mini_batch in range(num_samples / batch_size):
        mb_train_x, mb_train_target = get_mini_batch_stuffs()
        new_target_cost = sess.run(cross_entropy_target, feed_dict={x: mb_train_x, time: mb_train_time, target: mb_train_target})
        sess.run(tf.assign(cross_entropy_target_variable, new_target_cost))
        sess.run(opt_target, feed_dict={x: mb_train_x, target: mb_train_target})
```

Now, instead of the `cross_entropy_target` being calculated as part of the  `opt_target` graph, I am pre-calculating it, assigning it to a tensorflow variable, and expecting it to make use of that value.  This doesn't work at all.  The network's outputs never change.

I would expect these two code snippets to have equivalent outcomes. In both cases a feed forward is used to populate the values of `target` and `target_pred`, which is then reduced to the scalar value `cross_entropy_target`. This scalar value is used to inform the magnitude and direction of the gradient updates on the optimizer's `.minimize()`.

In this toy example there is no advantage to my calculating the cross_entropy_target "out of graph" and then assigning it to an in-graph `tf.Variable` for use in the `opt_target` run.  However, I have a real use case where my cost function is very complex and I have not been able to define it in terms of Tensorflow's existing tensor transforms.  Either way, I'd like to understand why using a `tf.Variable` for an optimizer's cost is incorrect use.

An interesting oddity that may be a byproduct of the solution to this:
If I set `cross_entropy_target_variable = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)`, running the `opt_target` will crash.  It requires that the cost value is modifiable.  Indeed, printing out its value before and after running the `opt_target` produces different values:

`cross_entropy_target before = 0.345796853304
cross_entropy_target after = 0.344796866179`

Why does running `minimize()` modify the value of the cost variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(` line, it looks at `cost`, which is `cross_entropy_target`, which is a `tf.Variable` op, and creates an optimizer which does nothing, since `cross_entropy_target` doesn't depend on any variables. Modifying `cross_entropy` target later has no effect because the optimizer has already been created.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks. My imperative mindset is clashing with tensorflow's graph-based approach. I wonder if I can achieve my goal with a placeholder where I feed-in the cost value. Otherwise I might have to give in and implement some custom ops in C++, which is the right and efficient way to do it anyway.

Comment: BTW, I made a wrapper that lets you use TensorFlow in imperative way -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/imperative

Comment: Unfortunately, using a placeholder for the cost value causes the same crash as using a non-trainable Variable for the cost value.  I'll work on reading the `minimize()` code to understand why.  Your imperative tensorflow is super cool, I'll give it a spin!